# ember route and templates not workking

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, routes

i have included a component in application.hbs

```
    <Auth></Auth>
```

next in the auh components i have the following code
auth.hbs

```
<form>
    <div class="text-field">
         <label>UserName:</label>
        <Input type="text" id="username" required />
        <span></span>
       
    </div>
    <div class="text-field">
        <label>Password:</label>
        <Input type="password" id="password" required />
        <span></span>
        
    </div>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <input {{action "buttonClick"}} type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

auth.js

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class AuthComponent extends Component {
  @service router;
   @service('index') auth;

  @action
  buttonClick() {
    let username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    let password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    console.log('user is ' + username);
    var dummy = this;
    dummy.router.replaceWith('demo');
    this.get('router.router').transitionTo('demo');
}
```

then the router demo
demo.hbs

```
{{#each @model as |post|}}
  <div>
    {{post.title}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

demo.js

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default class DemoRoute extends Route {
  @service router;
  async model() {
    return [
      { title: 'Ember Roadmap' },
      { title: 'Accessibility in Ember' },
      { title: 'EmberConf Recap' },
    ];
  }
}
```

so when i click the login button i need to view the contents returned from route but a new page is not viewed and only the login page is there but the url changes to http://localhost:8035/foodapp/#/demo but no changes to the page

router.js

```
import EmberRouter from '@ember/routing/router';
import config from 'foods/config/environment';

export default class Router extends EmberRouter {
  location = config.locationType;
  rootURL = config.rootURL;
}

Router.map(function () {
  // this.route('request', { path: '/req' });
  this.route('demo', { path: '/demo',resetNamespace: true });

  // this.route('index', { path: '/' }); // this is implicit, just putting it in for clarity
  // this.route('fo', function() {
  //   this.route('index', { path: '/' }); // this is implicit, just putting it in for clarity
  //   this.route('post', { path: '/:id' });
  // });

});
```

Can anyone help me with how can i view the template related with the route..how to get to a new page fropm the login page by transition to route..

environment.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (environment) {
  let ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'foods',
    environment,
    rootURL: '/',
    locationType: 'hash',
    EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
        // Here you can enable experimental features on an ember canary build
        // e.g. EMBER_NATIVE_DECORATOR_SUPPORT: true
      },
      EXTEND_PROTOTYPES: {
        // Prevent Ember Data from overriding Date.parse.
        Date: false,
      },
    },

    APP: {
      // Here you can pass flags/options to your application instance
      // when it is created
    },
  };

  if (environment === 'development') {
    // ENV.APP.LOG_RESOLVER = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = true;
  }

  if (environment === 'test') {
    // Testem prefers this...
    ENV.locationType = 'none';

    // keep test console output quieter
    ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = false;
    ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = false;

    ENV.APP.rootElement = '#ember-testing';
    ENV.APP.autoboot = false;
  }

  if (environment === 'production') {
    // here you can enable a production-specific feature
  }

  return ENV;
};
```

Comment: what version of ember-source are you using?

Comment: also! welcome! if you haven't already, I can't recommend this tutorial enough: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/part-1/ as it covers the concepts you're after

Comment: based on this info: `but the url changes to http://localhost:8035/foodapp/#/demo but no changes to the page` Can you also add the contents of your config/environment.js?

Comment: Thanks for the replies first and my ember version is 4.3.

Comment: I have updated my environment.js in question...it would be of great help if the problem is figured out...thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not familiar with the hash locationType -- any reason it's changed from history?
And have you gone through the tutorial?
Short of that, I think I'd need to play with a reproducton on my machine to see what's going on -- because of the unfamiliar setup -- so if you have a github repo reproducing teh problem, that'd be a huge help

Answer (score 1):

If `<Auth></Auth>` is your entire `application.hbs` this explains your problem!

It's important to understand, that the content of the `application.hbs` is *always* visible. It is like the top level route. So it needs an `{{outlet}}`, which will be the placeholder for any sub-route, like the `demo` in your example. So you'll need to add this.

Also `resetNamespace: true` does not make any sense in a top level route, and you should remove this.

Its important your `router.js` creates 3 routes:

- application

  - index
  - demo

If this does not help, can you verify you don't have any errors in your browser console, and specify the full path to all files you've listed, since then probably one of the paths is wrong.